# HTML5 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition always returns undefined

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

I am working on a project where geolocation is a needed feature, however I cannot currently test it on my work computer, as the coordinates are always undefined. I've tried multiple browsers, checked the privacy settings, and turned off my anti-virus. It still will not work, yet it works fine on my phone and another computer connected to the same network. The only difference I can think of is my computer is directly connected to the router, where as everything else uses wifi.

For example going to this website:
http://html5demos.com/geo
on my computer returns failed, from every browser, yet passes on my phone.

I get the following error code when testing myself from chrome:

```
 chrome :code: 2
message: Network location provider at 'https://www.googleapis.com/' : Returned error code 404.

firefox
"code: 2
message: Unknown error acquiring position
```

"

Comment: When the browser asks for confirmation regarding location permission, have you allowed it ?

Comment: Yes, that is not the issue

Comment: Because, when i tried the same link in my laptop, it is working

Comment: It also works for me, you may have disabled it ?
And you may have some plugins that disallow geolocation tracking maybe ?